# How do I simulate keystrokes and mouse clicks in an inactive window in Linux using Python?

Tags: python, linux

I want to automatically perform a click in a window, which does not have input focus. I saw the other posts about doing the same thing in windows but since I'm on linux, I don't think, that those libraries would work... Any idea, how I can achieve the same thing on Linux?

I tried window-input but that depends on pywin32 and when I try to install pywin32 I get this error-message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

Any ideas, how I can for that? Or is pywin32 simply not installable on a linux device?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) and even more precisely pynput.keyboard or pynput.mouse

Or [window-input](https://pypi.org/project/window-input/) (for installation use pip : `pip install window-input`)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one as soon as possible. The desceiption of the module looks promising...

Comment: Update: I tried to install it using pip, but it depends on pywin32 and when I try to install that, it tells me `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32` Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: mmmh thin pywin32 is for Windows. It seems that window_input is unusable on Linux ...
You can just try to code the details window_input asks you for as there doesn't seem to be a pywin32 equivalent for Linux.

Comment: The problem is that I can't even install window-input since pywin32 is a dependency of window-input. When I try to install window-input it automatically installs it's dependencies and throws an error while trying to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do. But [pyautogui's](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) function `pyautogui.click()` should be what you're looking after. If you're trying to right-click you should do `pyautogui.click(button='right')`.

Comment: My goal is to have two random applications. One in the foreground and one in the background. I want to create a script, which performs a repeating task, that always clicks in a certain window. Even if that window is currently in the background. That's why simulating a mouse-click is not enough. That would only work, if the window is already in the foreground.